# Javascript - Is possible to download a file using multiple connections from browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser, client-side

Is there a way to download a file through multiple connections using javascript from client side? in order to speed up a AJAX download file (more than 10mb size by example).
In the same way as do [AXEL](http://axel.alioth.debian.org/) or [ARIA2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/), or exist another method to accomplish this.

**Update**
I want to make a comic/manga viewer (I don't know why, I just want to make it) that support open CBZ, CBR and CBT files, and these file have a least 10 mb size.

Comment: Probably and maybe ....

Comment: Using ajax you could request the file in parts, each request getting a different part, then combine them client-side, but... you may have trouble at that point having the user download it in a cross-browser way (if you intended for it to be downloaded to their filesystem)

Comment: Tried using `a` element with `download` attribute set ? , webworkers ?

Comment: good point, @KevinB. The actual download is likely not part of the js engine, and not subject to the limitations of a single thread.

Comment: This is what "Download Managers" do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're limited to what the browser decides to do, unless you want to get crazy complicated, use extensions, WebRTC transfers, workers, etc.

Comment: Can I use 206 "Partial Content" request? and make them parallels and finally join using File API

Comment: @JaimeLeonardoSuncinCruz, the server set up would determine that. Not all servers implement 206.

Comment: What type of data are you downloading? 10MB is huge, more than a user can typically deal with unless you're talking audio or video, in which case streaming could be a better option so you don't have to wait for the entire file before starting to play it.

Comment: @JonathanM comic files (.cbz, cbt, .cbr) to view in browser, also images.

Comment: If you're able to program the server, you might consider having the server open the cb* files and display a page at a time with navigation.

Comment: @JonathanM I want to know how to speed up a download using javascript, this will be useful in multiple scenarios